# convert pdf Binary data into a viewable pdf

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, backend

I made a request from my express js back-end server  to an external server for a pdf file and this is the response I get.

```
response{

'%PDF-1.5\n' +
    '%����\n' +
    '3 0 obj\n' +
    '<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 224/Filter......'

}
```

I am assuming that this is the binary data of that pdf
if so then is there a way to convert and process this data in my express js server  into a viewable pdf file.
please help.

Comment: Hello! So, just to clarify some things. You would like to save the file on the server in a pdf format? Or would you like to view it on a client?

Comment: thank you for asking .I would like to convert the bin data to a pdf file and store it in my S3 bucket

Comment: thank you for this will give it a try now and update you:)

Comment: still not working please advise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm absurdly late, but here you go:

```js
res.status(200).header({ "Content-Type": "application/pdf" }).send(pdf);
//         ^             ^tells the browser that the
//         success        binary is a pdf
```

Hope this helps! (Either you, or someone else)

Comment: rather a late comment than no comment ..thanks ..atleast if someone else gets stuck on this they will find a solution here